# How to find strings that only contains two words (each words can only have A-Z or a-z characters)?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a couple of strings and I only want to display the string that has two words.

Each word can only contain A-Z or a-z

(Each string below has a new line)

```
"AIR CLEANING" <- true
"AIR CLN ASM C27w CLUTCH" <- false
"AIR COMPO. LUBRICATOR" <- false
"AIR COMP" <- true
"O-RING" <- false
```

Comment: Basicly, you are looking for strings with a length of at least three and a space in it?

Comment: Seems like a basic regular expression. start of sting, a thru z one or more times, space, a thru z one or more times, end of string.

Comment: isn't is possible to use regex? I tried this using \b and space between, but it does not work. https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/525

Comment: Are strings separated by new lines (line feed)?

Comment: @EduardoEscobar No, each string has a unique line.

Comment: How "AIR CLEANING" is separated from "AIR CLN ASM C27w CLUTCH"?

Comment: @EduardoEscobar string has two \b (words). "AIR CLN ASM C27w CLUTCH" has 5x \b.

Comment: I cant use string.split(" ").length as I uses multiple different regex methods and checking other stuffs..

Comment: `^(?:\w+(?:\h+|\b)){2}$`?

Comment: @EduardoEscobar is asking are these separate strings you are testing or is it a big block of text

Comment: @EduardoEscobar separate strings.

Comment: @IsakLaFleur, if they're separated by new lines (\n), this should work for you https://regex101.com/r/8tV5DB/2

Comment: @Jerodev Not possible to use string.split(" ").length here as I can only allow  A-Z/i in each word... It is solved now. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a start and end sign and check the wanted characters with a group, separated by white space.

```js
var array = ["AIR CLEANING", "AIR CLN ASM C27w CLUTCH", "AIR COMPO. LUBRICATOR", "AIR COMP", "O-RING"];

console.log(array.map(s => /^[A-Z]+\s+[A-Z]+$/i.test(s)));
```

Answer (score 1):

This trivial task and can be done without the variability of a Regex, by simply using javascript.

```js
let string = `AIR CLEANING
AIR CLN ASM C27w CLUTCH
AIR COMPO. LUBRICATOR
AIR COMP
O-RING`;

let splitSpace = string.split('\n');
let result = splitSpace.map(x => x.split(' ').length === 2 ? true : false);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi Rick! Thank you for your answer. This solution does not verify if each word has only A-Z/i chars. Thats why I needed to use regex.

Answer (score 1):

This is very straightforward with regular expressions:

```js
var rx = /^\w+\s+\w+$/

console.log(rx.test("AIR CLEANING"))
console.log(rx.test("AIR CLN ASM C27w CLUTCH"))
console.log(rx.test("AIR COMPO. LUBRICATOR"))
console.log(rx.test("AIR COMP"))
console.log(rx.test("O-RING"))
```

This will consider something like 'Hello3' a word. So the line: 'hello3 27test' would be true. It will also consider multiple spaces as one space.

Comment: \w allow also 0-9 which does not work for me. Nina's answer used A-Z/i that solved it. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = ["AIR CLEANING", "AIR CLN ASM C27w CLUTCH", "AIR COMPO. LUBRICATOR", "AIR COMP", "O-RING"];

console.log(
    array.map(e => (e.split(" ").length == 2) ? true : false )
   )
```